# Merge two objects by join field in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, merge, mapping, lookup

I have project details , which I am getting from two calles, first call contains few fields and another one contains few fields of project details. I have to merge.

`projectDetails1`

```
[{
  ProjectID: 284,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-30",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-00",
}, {
  ProjectID: 285,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-11",
}, {
  ProjectID: 286,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-22",
}, {
  ProjectID: 287,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}, {
  ProjectID: 288,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}]
```

`projectDetails2`

```
[{
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-00",
  Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}, {
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-11",
  Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}]
```

Need to merge both and by **aID** and **a_ID** is common(joining) fields.

`finalProjectDeatils`

```
[{
  ProjectID: 284,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-30",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-00",
  Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}, {
  ProjectID: 285,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-11",
  Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}, {
  ProjectID: 286,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-22",
}, {
  ProjectID: 287,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}, {
  ProjectID: 288,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce to merge each item under its AID or a_ID key, then take the values of the resulting object.

Concatenate the two arrays.

```js
const [...d1, ...d2]
```

Run reduce on the combined array.

```js
const [...d1, ...d2].reduce( // ....
```

Within the reducer function, extract AID from the item, and use a_ID as a fallback. This captures the id in AID for either case and has the side effect of removing `a_ID` from the results. Capture the remaining attributes with a rest operator (`...other`).

```js
.reduce(acc, {a_ID, AID = a_ID, ...other}) => // ...
```

Merge the attributes into the accumulator object under the ID key. If the key has already been encountered this will merge the current item's attributes into the prior entry. Return the updated accumulator for the next iteration.

```js
acc[AID] = { AID, ...acc[AID], ...other };
return acc;
```

Finally, extract the merged values via Object.values.

```js
const merged = Object.values(byId);
```

```js
const d1 = [{
  ProjectID: 284,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-30",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-00",
}, {
  ProjectID: 285,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-11",
}, {
  ProjectID: 286,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-22",
}, {
  ProjectID: 287,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}, {
  ProjectID: 288,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}];
  
const d2 = [{
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-00",
  Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}, {
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-11",
  Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}];

const byId = [...d1, ...d2].reduce((acc, {a_ID, AID = a_ID, ...other}) => {
  acc[AID] = { AID, ...acc[AID], ...other };
  return acc;
}, {});

const merged = Object.values(byId);

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: That's a very nice trick!

Comment: This is working well but, in my case, some projects in d1 objects AID values is null. those recored are missing in final output. how can I get those also. I changed in the my question also.

Comment: @Sun while looking fancy, not efficient, there no need in intermediate arrays, objects. more 3x slower than usual `Array::map()`, check the benchmark in my answer

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... more important, the approach itself is not suited for the OP's data, due to any item of the `projectDetails1` array could possibly feature a `null` value at its `AID` property which results in suppressing any other item that actually carries an entry like `AID: null` except of the first occurring/processed one of this kind.

Comment: @PeterSeliger a nice find, seems the solution doesn't work

Comment: OP's data changed after the fact. It solves the originally stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the OP's provided data structures and therefore in order to not miss on any project data, one only should choose a solution which follows a lookup-based approach e.g. via [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

As for the OP's data base, one has to first [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `projectDetails2` array into an array of entries (key-value pair/tuple), where the (lookup) key equals/relates a "Details 2"-item's `a_ID` value. One also would immediately [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) such an item into said key and the item's [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)-data, thus `a_ID` not being anymore part of any now newly created "Details 2" data-item.

The final step then is just another simple `map` task (this time mapping `projectDetails1`), where for each "Details 1"-item one does create a new item as merger (based on [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) of said "Details 1"-item and the looked-up `AID` based "Details 2"-item. In case the latter can not be looked-up/referred the merger happens with just the current processed item into the empty object.

```js
const projectDetails1 = [{
  ProjectID: 284,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-30",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-00",
}, {
  ProjectID: 285,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-11",
}, {
  ProjectID: 286,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: "B1124-022571-22",
}, {
  ProjectID: 287,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}, {
  ProjectID: 288,
  ProjectName: "Test Project June-28",
  Budget: 10000,
  BudgetMoney: "10,000.00",
  BriefStatus: "Approved",
  ProjectStatus: "Estimating",
  AID: null,
}];
  
const projectDetails2 = [{
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-00",
  Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}, {
  a_ID: "B1124-022571-11",
  Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
  End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  Project_Type_ID: 12,
  Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)",
  Active_YN: "Y",
  Committed_Revenue: 3000000,
  Revenue: 4000000,
}];

const aidBasedMergeDataLookup = new Map(
  projectDetails2
    .map(({ a_ID, ...mergeData }) => [a_ID, mergeData])
);

const mergedProjectDetails = projectDetails1
  .map(dataItem => Object.assign(
    {}, dataItem, aidBasedMergeDataLookup.get(dataItem.AID)
  ));

console.log({ mergedProjectDetails });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: there're several performance problems with the solution. first preparing a map is quite expensive and the potential performance boost depends on the data size. preparing data for benchmarking is hard but with the OP's data size it's slower than `Array::find()`. I've benchmarked and a solution with `Map` was definitively slower. Second the spreading is very slow comparing to `Object.assign()`, check the benchmark in my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... The spreading is slow, indeed. I changed it to `Object.assign`. The `Map` based approach on the other hand does proof itself to be very performant (that's what `Map` was designed for). It will outperform any `find` based approach already with only a few more items in `projectDetails1`.

Comment: You don't need `??` , `Object.assign()` ignores `undefined`

Comment: Using `Object.assign()` made it a lot faster, the only problem that `Map` is slower with such small array data... I'll prepare a big arrays later, the problem is to create unique IDs...

Comment: i guess we could mutually upvote our answer due the such productive collab, upvoted yours

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... regarding the hint for `Object.assign` and undefined values, I id update the example code accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... I usually neither beg for nor mutually trade votes. I also don't want to support a `find` based approach. Nevertheless I already voted lately in favor of a couple of your answers.

Comment: i see, thanks! not removing my vote )

Answer (score 0):

Make a a lookup object out of `projectDetails2`:

```
const projectDetails2Lookup = {}
projectDetails2.forEach(item => {
  item = { ...item }
  projectDetails2Lookup[item.a_ID] = { ...item }
  delete item.a_ID
})
```

Then merge each element from `projectDetails1` with a corresponding element from the lookup object, if possible:

```
const finalProjectDetails = projectDetails1.map(item =>
  ({
    ...item,
    ...(projectDetails2Lookup[item.AID] ?? {})
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner: use `Object.assign()` to merge the 2 objects into a new one. The second object is found with `Array::find()`. If not found it returns `undefined` and ignored by `Object::assign()`.

The only drawback is that `a_ID` is left, but if it's not used, that's no problem imho. Otherwise delete it with `delete`.

```js
const projectDetails1 = [ { ProjectID: 284, ProjectName: "Test Project June-30", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-00", }, { ProjectID: 285, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-11", }, { ProjectID: 286, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-22", }, { ProjectID: 287, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, }, { ProjectID: 288, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, } ]   
const projectDetails2 = [ { a_ID: "B1124-022571-00", Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, { a_ID: "B1124-022571-11", Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, ]; 
  
const merged = projectDetails1.map(p1 => Object.assign({}, p1, projectDetails2.find(p2 => p2.a_ID === p1.AID)));

console.log('Merged:', merged)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to modify the first array:

```js
const projectDetails1 = [ { ProjectID: 284, ProjectName: "Test Project June-30", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-00", }, { ProjectID: 285, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-11", }, { ProjectID: 286, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-22", }, { ProjectID: 287, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, }, { ProjectID: 288, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, } ]   
const projectDetails2 = [ { a_ID: "B1124-022571-00", Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, { a_ID: "B1124-022571-11", Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, ]; 
  
projectDetails1.forEach(p1 => Object.assign(p1, projectDetails2.find(p2 => p2.a_ID === p1.AID)));

console.log('Merged:', projectDetails1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Benchmarking with the others solutions:
[image]

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script benchmark count="10000">
const projectDetails1 = [ { ProjectID: 284, ProjectName: "Test Project June-30", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-00", }, { ProjectID: 285, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-11", }, { ProjectID: 286, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: "B1124-022571-22", }, { ProjectID: 287, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, }, { ProjectID: 288, ProjectName: "Test Project June-28", Budget: 10000, BudgetMoney: "10,000.00", BriefStatus: "Approved", ProjectStatus: "Estimating", AID: null, } ]   
const projectDetails2 = [ { a_ID: "B1124-022571-00", Start_Date: "2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2023-05-02T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, { a_ID: "B1124-022571-11", Start_Date: "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z", End_Date: "2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z", Project_Type_ID: 12, Project_Type: "Ext. Delivery (T&M)", Active_YN: "Y", Committed_Revenue: 3000000, Revenue: 4000000, }, ]; 
 
// @benchmark Peter's solution

const aidBasedMergeDataLookup = new Map(
  projectDetails2
    .map(({ a_ID, ...mergeData }) => [a_ID, mergeData])
);

projectDetails1
  .map(dataItem => Object.assign(
    {}, dataItem, aidBasedMergeDataLookup.get(dataItem.AID)
  ));

// @benchmark ray's solution

const byId = [...projectDetails1, ...projectDetails2].reduce((acc, {a_ID, AID = a_ID, ...other}) => {
  acc[AID] = { AID, ...acc[AID], ...other };
  return acc;
}, {});

Object.values(byId);
 
// @benchmark Alexander's solution
projectDetails1.map(p1 => Object.assign({}, p1, projectDetails2.find(p2 => p2.a_ID === p1.AID)));

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```